# Z3py cannot solve the power operator

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm new to Z3py, and I used the lastest z3py z3-4.4.2.4e7a867cd995-x64-win. But, I just wonder why z3py cannot solve the following code.

```
from z3 import *
x = Int('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x**2 == 4)
print s.check()
```

I got *unknow* rather than *sat*.

Answer (score 0):

When `x = Int('x')` is changed into `x = Real('x')`, you can get a *sat*.

I think the regulation of solving an evolution equation has a rule that the type of variable should be `Real`.